# No implicit conversion of Integer into Array

Tags: ruby

I am doing a ruby challenege in leetcode where I have to remove duplicates in a array and return the array with unique values. I keep getting:

```
Line 55: no implicit conversion of Integer into Array (TypeError) in serializer__.rb (-)
```

and my answer is:

```
def remove_duplicates(nums)
    nums.sort.each_with_index do |num,i|
        if nums[i + 1].eql? num
            nums.delete_at(i)
        end
    end
    
    nums
end
```

I was not able to find a clear solution to what I need to do to resolve this. Please let me know what I need to do.

Comment: The problem is probably that you delete records from the array (what changes its size) while iterating it. Why don't you just use [`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq)?

Comment: So using Array#uniq was my first go to and I keep getting the same error. I even used Array#to_set

Comment: Please provide a link to the Leetcode problem, as it seems questionable that the problem is as simple as it appears.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/

Comment: What is `nums`? Please provide input/output expectations

Comment: nums is the array of Integers that gets inputed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working example**

you need to re-read the question ... you have to replace the nums, and return the count of the remaining figures:

```
def remove_duplicates(nums)
  nums.uniq!
  nums.count
end
```

you have been returning the array, not the count of the array.

**Adjustments to original code**

to do it with your original code (note that the array should already be sorted, according to the question):

```
def remove_duplicates(nums)
  nums.each_with_index do |num,i|
    if nums[i + 1].eql? num
       nums.delete_at(i)
    end
  end
    
  nums.count
end
```

**Working example with Unsorted initial array**

if you wanted an answer that worked when the code is not sorted (which is not the case with your particular question, but a commenter seems to ask about this), and you need to generate a sorted unique array, overwriting the original array, and returning the size of the new array, you would need to do something like the following:

```
def remove_duplicates(nums)
  nums.replace(nums.uniq.sort)
  nums.count
end
```

Comment: The "original code" will still not work reliably since the index `i` refers to the index of the element in the sorted array, but is used to delete an element in the original (unsorted) `nums` array which may refer to an entirely different element.

Comment: I agree, but since the array was already sorted, in this particular case it probably shouldn't fail ... however I will remove the sort from my answer

Comment: Now, as the algorithm only removes subsequent duplicates from the array, if the source `nums` array is NOT sorted, you won't remove all duplicates. Even worse, now the `nums` array is changed in place while you are iterating over it. This is generally undefined behaviour and will likely lead to incorrect results.

Comment: URL he provided: problems/ ... remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array ... "Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order" ... the array is already sorted, his sorting was irrelevant to the question. I would not do it the way that he's doing it (the reason that I gave my working code), however I thought it prudent to show how he could have made something that "passed" with only a minor change to his code